# iPhone Dev: How to get string format attributes like NSLog

Tags: iphone, string, format, nslog

I'm trying to wrap NSLog function just to add some info every time I log something, but I have a problem.

The NSLog declaration is

```
void NSLog(NSString *format, ...) __attribute__((format(__NSString__,1,2)))
```

this allow to have multiple parameters in call as

```
NSLog(@"first %@ second %@ third %d,string,string,number);
```

My declaration function is similar

```
  void LogUtil(id sender, int level, NSString *str, ...) __attribute__((format(__NSString__,3,4)))
```

and the implementation is just

```
void LogUtil(id sender, int level, NSString *str, ...){
  if(level>=LEVEL){
    NSLog(@"<%@> %@",sender,str);
  }
}
```

So I'm able to call it right as

```
NSLog(self, 1, @"first %@ second %@ third %d,string,string,number);
```

but in this case the attributes won't evaluated.

So, I think I have to do something in my implementation to formatting str with paramters but how??

thaks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is full description of that in:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html

Comment: @Achile, don't forget to accept @Guy's answer. Just click the "v" near his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks...this is working implementation

```
    void LogUtil(id sender, int level, NSString *str, ...){

      if(level>=LEVEL){
        va_list args;
        va_start(args,str);
        NSString *format=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:str arguments:args];
        va_end(args);  
        NSLog(@"<%@> %@",sender,format);
        [format release];
      }

    }
```

Comment: I suggest you to put the entire function code inside the "if" statement `if(level>=LEVEL)`...